# Should anova(model, test="Chisq") not produce a test statistic as well as a P value?

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

Doing a poisson regression like this: `model<-glm(y~x*z,family=poisson)` with one predictor being a factor, I would use `anova(model,test="Chisq")` to test the overall effect of the interaction rather than `summary(model)`, which would give me two interaction terms (one for each of two levels in the factor variable that is not the intercept).

When I do this, I get an output with five columns:

`Df, Deviance, Resid. Df, Resid.Dev, Pr(>Chi)`

If I do the same with `test="F"` instead I get an F value, so I assume there is a reason R doesn't report a chi-squared or LRT value.

Is this right? I would have thought that I should report a test statistic with my P value. Can I calculate it from the residual deviance and residual degrees of freedom? Should I report the residual deviance and df with my P value and leave it at that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben Bolker answers this question in a response to another question here: [Comparing nested GLMs via chi-squared and loglikelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69664/comparing-nested-glms-via-chi-squared-and-loglikelihood)

Apparently, for the purposes of reporting anova(model, test="Chisq") results, the Deviance may be reported as the chi-squared value, though reporting it as Deviance would be more informative.

See also this GLM manual on [stat.colombia.edu](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~martin/W2024/R11.pdf&ei=PqdCU43_CsXx0gWDvoCwDQ&usg=AFQjCNG9C2OKmJDTSiafrpOgNwrN9ZC7eQ&sig2=SZ73M0bju5mWia4cPApbtA&bvm=bv.64125504,d.d2k)