# Comparing Gamma GLMS using Analysis of Deviance

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution

Im new to stats/R and have just started a course on generalized linear models and am a little confused. Im comparing two gamma glms using analysis of deviance to see whether m0 is a reasonable simplification of m1. I also need to test whether or not the two predictors ajwtr and perypc are not significant at a 5% level, however I'm having trouble interpreting my output.
[image]

[image]

[image]

if anyone could explain how to interpret the output to me that would be very helpful!

Comment: Why are you taking the exponential of your outcome and using an identity link?

Comment: that's just the way the example was done

Comment: is it possible for you to narrow down on which parts you have problems with? The analysis of deviance is like a likelihood ratio test, you can check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69664/comparing-nested-glms-via-chi-squared-and-loglikelihood